# Number displays in scientific notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting a json response back with my data but when I am trying to use one of the values (number) the response is converting to scientific notation. I never encountered something like this so I am just going to post what is happening.

When I use `console.log(response)` the value looks like that `doctorid":2015031216033174968087` and when I am trying to use the doctorid the value becomes `2.015031216033175e+21`. This happens even if I output the value in the console by using `console.log(response.doctorid)`. Any idea what might be causing such a behavior?

Comment: Javascript numbers don't have that much precision.

Comment: I have this code up and running for over a year now without this issue though...

Comment: Then you probably had smaller numbers.

Comment: My numbers follow always the same pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike python and ruby, Javascript doesn't support arbitrary precision integers. The maximal numeric value that can be exactly represented in JS is [`9007199254740991`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). Bigger numbers have an approximate representation and are converted to strings using scientific notation.

The only way to avoid that in your case is to encode IDs as strings in JSON:

```
"doctorid": "2015031216033174968087"
```

Comment: "Numbers greater than that are converted to floats" --- that's incorrect (at least it must be rephrased). **EVERY** number in JS is an IEEE 754 double.

Comment: That's probably going to fix my issue. I will try it and accept your answer if it works. Thanks

Comment: "can only be displayed as floats" --- that's ugly as well. Representation has nothing to do with the data behind it.

Comment: @zerkms: well, I did my best ;) If you have a better idea how to express what I meant here, feel free to edit.

Comment: I would just remove that complete phrase. " The maximal integer value JS can work with is 9007199254740991" states all one needs to know. If they need more - they go to ES and IEEE 754 specification :-)

Comment: @zerkms: turned CW, feel free to edit.