# Retrieve coordinates from firebase to number

Tags: android, location, firebase

I have coordinates saved in firebase, such as this:

```
lat: 19535037.77154548
lng: -4578925.543895042
```

But when I try to load them into a number it changes it to something like `1.953503777154548E7`

```
static double homeLat;
Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            homeLat = (double) snapshot.child("lat").getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I have tried changing it from double to int and various others, but it errors out and tells me it needs to be double.  Yet double changes the decimal placing and adds the E7 to the end.

I'm not going to lie, i'm pretty new to java and having to assign types of numbers.  But I have been reading for awhile now with not much luck as to why I am getting this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the same value, but then using scientific notation. You'll have to convert it into your preferred output format when you need to display it (which you code doesn't).

See [Number displays in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021197/number-displays-in-scientific-notation)